# Copy specific fonts referenced in CSS to the target folder using Laravel mix (Webpack)

Tags: css, webpack, fonts

I have Laravel 5.5 and using `mix` to automatically generate files in the `public` folder and `yarn` for package management.
When fonts are referenced by a SASS file located in the package folder (`node_modules/package_name/module.scss`) and that file is processed by `mix.sass()`, these fonts are automatically placed into `public/fonts/vendor/package_name` folder and URLs in the resulting CSS file are replaced by the new font files location paths.

Now, I would like to copy only some fonts defined in the package, while the package .scss file loads all of them.
For that, instead of using `node_modules/package_name/module.scss` I created a custom file (`_fonts.scss`), and referenced it the main SASS file:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font-Name';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('node_modules/package_name/fonts/font-name.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Can I configure Webpack to replace URL to `public/fonts/vendor/package_name/font-name.ttf` in the resulting .css and copy font file to that place?

I can just write that final URL into source `_fonts.css` and call `mix.copy()` to manually copy fonts, but I feel that this is the wrong way.

Also, is there a nice way to copy these fonts to a custom folder `public/fonts/custom`?

Comment: I've amended your title to remove the *opinion-based* best way requirement which might have had a negative impact. Other than that the question is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking mix's `webpack-rules.js` file, I decided that described functionality should work by default without any additional work:

```
rules.push({
    test: /\.(woff2?|ttf|eot|svg|otf)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
        name: path => {
            if (! /node_modules|bower_components/.test(path)) {
                return 'fonts/[name].[ext]?[hash]';
            }

            return 'fonts/vendor/' + path
                .replace(/\\/g, '/')
                .replace(
                    /((.*(node_modules|bower_components))|fonts|font|assets)\//g, ''
                ) + '?[hash]';
        },
        publicPath: Config.resourceRoot
    }
});
```

And then, while reading a nice [article](https://shellmonger.com/2016/01/22/working-with-fonts-with-webpack/) about loading fonts I saw that paths in `.scss` **must be relative**.
So I changed fonts path from

```
node_modules/package_name/fonts
```

to

```
./../../../../../node_modules/package_name/fonts
```

and now it works.